# Is there a Maximum force rating?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

I'm curious what the current maximum force rating is.

EDIT:
Originally I had asked in regards to specs but with new info about character advancement I found out that the original question is making no sense any longer as you can take every spec (aside from those that are the same between books there only one of them like the force sensitive in edge of empire and age of rebellion which is the same spec):
[Taking out-of-career specialisations](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49622/taking-out-of-career-specialisations)

So the question now would be what is the real maximum force rating? Characteristics are restricted to 6, skills to 5 (naturally lower each at char creation).

What about force rating does it have a maximum?
With all the current specs added together: About 12 force rating is possible (maxed out all specs).

So the question like I said is: is there a max to force rating ruleswise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The fastest progression to 6 is now 395XP. By swapping Padawan (from *Rise of the Separatists*) with Pathfinder.

No, there is no cap on Force Rating *yet*. It is likely there will never be an official one.

You've actually done your math wrong, so let me clarify that. You are granted a Force Rating 1, either by an F&D career or one of the FSEs. Each FSE has a single Force Rating talent, adding +1. F&D contains 13 Force Rating granting specializations, two of which contain two Force Rating talents. That means a total Force Rating of 18.

What you have to remember is that Force Rating isn't a characteristic. It doesn't start at an average of two and it can't be bought at character creation. That means the minimum (I mean, literally the absolute minimum) XP necessary to reach a Force Rating of 6 is:

- F&D Career grants Force Rating 1
- 135XP - Sage +2 FR
- 30XP - Cross-career multi-spec
- 140XP - Seer +2 FR
- 40XP - Cross-career multi-spec
- 65XP - Pathfinder +1 FR
- Total 410XP

All of that (~300XP worth of sessions) and the only thing you have that uses your Force Rating is the Animal Empathy talent. Even when you start buying Force Powers, remember that when something says you spend Force Points for an effect, many of them are not per point. You'll have to buy upgrades (or other talents) to make use of that higher force rating.

Also keep in mind that that's just for FR6. Hitting FR7 will require another 120XP with no additional Force Rating-based gains. And the price just keeps going up. Realistically only a dedicated force user (ie: one who only ever uses Force Powers) is likely to reach FR6, let alone exceed it. So there is no RAW limit because there doesn't really need to be.